# Development compromises in using Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

1. The case for event-driven microservices such as Spring Cloud Stream is their asynchronous nature, which I do agree it makes them more scalable
2. But I have an issue regarding how to code it in a way where I don't lose certain key features that I have access to using synchronous services
3. In a servlet-based MS, I make full use of servlet context variables and servlet-based Spring autowiring functions
4. For e.g., I leverage heavily on HTTP headers to carry metadata between microservices without having to impact the payload. But in Spring Cloud Stream using Kafka, Kafka doesn't support message headers of any kind! I lose that immediately if I use SCS. Putting them into the payload causes all sort of changes in my model classes if I define the attributes clearly. Yes, I can use a simple Hashmap to simulate the HTTP header object but it really seems like reinventing the wheel to me.
5. On the auto-wiring side: I maintain an audit log record per request, which I implement by declaring a request-scoped Hashmap bean and autowiring it into any methods in the Servlet's call stack that needs to append data to the audit log. Basically it's just a global variable to hold some data within a single request. But in SCS, again, I lose that cos bean scopes that leverage on servlets are not available.
6. So far, there seems to be a lot of trade-offs that I have to make just to make Spring Cloud Stream work for me.
7. I thought about an alternative approach where I use SCS just to create an entry point but the Source method would just get the event, use a Processor to construct a HTTP request and send the request along to a HTTP endpoint. But, why go through all that trouble then?

Hoping that some more experienced devs would be able to shed some light on how they leverage on SCS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@feicipet Thanks for the detailed question. let me try to address some of your concerns in the order you have listed them:

1. +1
2. +1
3. I am not sure why you are referring to it as servlet-based instead of Spring-based? Those are features provided by Spring, but read on. . .
4. Spring Cloud Stream doesn't use Kafka, the end user does while Spring Cloud Stream provides Kafka binder allowing Spring Cloud Stream to integrate with Kafka. Further more, while Kafka indeed did not support headers prior to version 0.11, Spring Cloud Stream always supported and will continue support headers even with Kafka pre-0.11, embedding them in the Message and then extracting them in the consumer side into the proper Message headers completely transparent to the end user. In other words one would assume that Kafka did support headers by simply using Spring Cloud Stream. With Kafka 0.11+ headers are supported natively and we have adjusted to that with the same level of transparency.
   So, you don't need to put anything in the payload. Just create an appropriate `Message<payload, headers>` and SCSt will take care of the rest regardless of the broker (Kafka, Rabbit, Foo etc.).
5. Yes you do simply due to the fact that as you eluded earlier SCSt promotes an asynchronous and stateless architecture. However, I do not agree that what you are trying to accomplish is un-accomplishable. Rather it is accomplishable the way you are describing, but there are other way to maintain context and I would be more then glad to discuss it as a separate topic.
6. I would not call them trade-offs, rather difference in the architecture, that has its benefits, but it is a not one-size-fits-all architecture and therefore its viability should be discussed within the context of a concrete use case.
7. +1. You don't have to separate it as Source and Processor. You can simply create a custom Source app with exposed REST endpoint and custom processing logic. However we are currently working on enhancements i the framework to ensure that you could do the same with the existing starter apps.

Obviously we have touched on many points here and some of them would probably need to be debated further, but I hope this clears up some of your concerns.

Cheers

Comment: Hmmm... didn't realize SCS would wrap its own header implementation even if the transport level did not support it. As long as we have this, I think it's a step forward for me in trying to get this to work. I'll look into this, thank you!